# .Net Protocol Buffers to JSON, JsonFormatReader class does not handle outmost curly braces?

Tags: json, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c, protobuf-csharp-port

I am working on using Google Protocol Buffers, using the protobuf-csharp-port library (https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/).
The Google.ProtocolBuffers.Serialization class has a `JsonFormatReader` / `JsonFormatWriter` class, when I use them they do not place beginning and ending curly braces to the JSON document, nor they can read the same document they write if I add beginning and ending braces.

So for example Calling

```
        PB.ProtoBufMessage message = CreateMyMessage();

        string json;
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ICodedOutputStream output = JsonFormatWriter.CreateInstance(sw);

            message.WriteTo(output);
            output.Flush();
            json = sw.ToString();
        }
```

Creates:

```
"\"field1\":\"prop1\",\"field2\":1,\"subitem\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0}"
```

If I try to parse

```
String jsonmessage = "{\"field1\":\"prop1\",\"field2\":1,\"subitem\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"z\":0}}"
```

using

```
    PB.ProtoBufMessage copy;
    ICodedInputStream input = JsonFormatReader.CreateInstance(jsonmessage);
    copy = PB.ProtoBufMessage.CreateBuilder().MergeFrom(input).Build();
```

I get the following:

```
(1:1) error: Unexpected token '{', expected: '"'.

   at Google.ProtocolBuffers.Serialization.JsonCursor.Assert(Boolean cond, Char expected)
   at Google.ProtocolBuffers.Serialization.JsonCursor.Consume(Char ch)
   at Google.ProtocolBuffers.Serialization.JsonCursor.ReadString()
   at Google.ProtocolBuffers.Serialization.JsonFormatReader.PeekNext(String& field)
   at Google.ProtocolBuffers.Serialization.AbstractReader.Google.ProtocolBuffers.ICodedInputStream.ReadTag(UInt32& fieldTag, String& fieldName)
   at ...
```

Why is the { } missing, and is this valid JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write/read message start/end. Like:

```
output.WriteMessageStart();
message.WriteTo(output);
output.WriteMessageEnd();
```

Similary wilhe reading:

```
input.ReadMessageStart();
builder.MergeFrom(input);
input.ReadMessageEnd();
```

The above code works with json and binary reader/writers.